# C# Conditonal Formatting dynamically generated controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've attempted to dynamically create tabs depending on how many groups of data I have in a file (settlementPeriod), each with their own table on them.

I've then added the created tables and added them to a List of DataGridViews, in order to manipulate them later.

```
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
tableList.Add(dgv);
```

---

```
foreach (var dgv in tableList)
    for (int l = 0; l < dgv.Rows.Count; l++)
```

However, the program returns a null set for the tableRows (dgv.Rows) and never enters the loop. It only returns data for DataGridViews that are not dyanamically generated. (For example if I addded dataGridView1 to the tableList)

---

I've attempted to iterate through the list of tabs (as there's only one table per tab), but to no success either

```
foreach(var page in tabList)
    DataGridView dgv = page.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>() as DataGridView;
```

---

I've included all relevant code below. Any help is appreciated.
For reference "results" is a class of data.
Thanks//.

```
private List<DataGridView> tableList = new List<DataGridView>();

private void CreateTables()
{
        var listItemsBySettlementPeriod = results.GroupBy(items => items.settlementPeriod)
                            .Select(group => group.ToList())
                            .ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < listItemsBySettlementPeriod.Count(); i++)
        {
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(listItemsBySettlementPeriod[i][0].settlementPeriod);
            tabList.Add(tabControl1.TabPages[(i + 1)]);

            DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
            tableList.Add(dgv);
            dgv.Height = 300;    dgv.Width = 1200;

            DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            DataRow row;
            string[] header = {"bidType", "date", "unitID", "price", "offerVolume"};

            for (int j = 0; j < listItemsBySettlementPeriod[i].Count(); j++)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                    for (int k = 0; k < header.Count(); k++)
                        dt.Columns.Add(header[k], typeof(string));

                row = dt.NewRow();
                foreach (var value in listItemsBySettlementPeriod[i])
                {
                    row[0] = value.bidType;
                    row[1] = value.acceptTime;
                    row[2] = value.unitID;
                    row[3] = value.price;
                    row[4] = value.volume;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            dgv.DataSource = dt;  
            tabControl1.TabPages[(i + 1)].Controls.Add(dgv);
        }

        foreach (var dgv in tableList)
        {
            for (int l = 0; l < dgv.Rows.Count; l++) //CONDITIONAL FORMATING
            {
                string val = "";
                if (dgv.Rows[l].Cells[0].Value != null)
                    val = dgv.Rows[l].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                if (val == "OFFER")
                    dgv.Rows[l].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
                else if (val == "BID")
                    dgv.Rows[l].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
                else
                    dgv.Rows[l].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            }
            dgv.Refresh();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until the control is actually drawn (shown), no data binding is applied to it, etc.

So remove the last foreach loop from your method.

Do conditional formatting with the `RowPrePaint` event.

```
...
dgv.DataSource = dt;
dgv.RowPrePaint += Dgv_RowPrePaint; // subscribe to event
...
```

Event handler:

```
private void Dgv_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
    var dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
    var row = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    var val = row.Cells[0].Value?.ToString();

    if (val == "OFFER")
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
    else if (val == "BID")
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
    else
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
}
```

---

Also, do not use `dgv.Refresh()`. Very often I see in the code how this `Refresh` method is used for nothing. It is meaningless in this context.

Comment: Thanks. That fix has worked perfectly! You're a life saver :D